How to use NPM package in WasmJsMain?
I have installed the uuid NPM package for WasmJsMain target in build.gradle.kts
@OptIn(ExperimentalWasmDsl::class)
    wasmJs {
        moduleName = "composeApp"

        browser {
            val projectDirPath = project.projectDir.path

            commonWebpackConfig {
                outputFileName = "composeApp.js"
                devServer = (devServer ?: KotlinWebpackConfig.DevServer()).apply {
                    static = (static ?: mutableListOf()).apply {
                        // Serve sources to debug inside browser
                        add(projectDirPath)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        binaries.executable()

        dependencies {
            implementation(npm("uuid", "10.0.0"))
        }
    }

And I would like to use it. I tried to access it using external require declaration with no luck.
package ...

import kotlinx.browser.window

external fun require(module: String): dynamic // error here

val uuid = require("uuid")

fun generate(): String = uuid.v4() as String

The error says:

Type dynamic cannot be used in external function return. Only
external, primitive, string and function types are supported in
Kotlin/Wasm JS interop.

I tried to search various examples on GitHub but I cannot find any use of a NPM package like this.
How can I use the uuid package from WasmJsMain? Is there some package manager I should use?

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].
